How could I set up a private network on Linux that could hold IP cameras in the future?
I've been googling this kind of question a lot but I couldn't find the clearest answer so I thought I'd specify here what kind of setup I need and what would be the most efficient way to do that.
I use Linux Mint and Ubuntu on all computers. I'd like to create an internal network with no access to the Internet, connecting my computers through physical LAN connection so I have a network where I can only interact between my devices and they can't receive traffic from external network, providers, etc.
I'd like that system to support my IP cameras which I'd like to also connect on that private, local network, presumably with one computer to act as a server for that.
How could I achieve this?
Thank you, sorry if the question is too broad, I'm happy to specify and clarify.

This is the purpose of a router or router OS [Sophos UTM / Firewall (Linux-based), pFsense (BSD-based), etc.]

To answer your question,
You do not need to do anything very special.

Make sure the IP cameras you get have their own webpage you connect to, or have the availability to connect to a server software that is free to use and setup. Or the easier thing: Make sure they do NOT connect to the cloud or any cloud software. This requirement is so that you can install them in your local network without any external network access.

For the network: Use any router you would like, just do not connect your ISP's cable to its WAN port. Thus the router will have no external network access, and by connecting any devices to the router's WiFi or its LAN ports, the devices will be isolated in the router's network. This includes the IP cameras. You can then configure the IP cameras to have static IPs in your router's settings to make sure you can access them on an address you know.
The alternative here is a router OS, as mentioned by @JW0914 in the comments. You can install such an OS on any PC/laptop, and it can act as the router, but it could require extra configuration.



Sorry for the late response. What should go into the router's WAN port, then? Nothing at all?

@xxxVxxxlinux nothing at all, yes.

Ok, I set up a router without internet, connected two computers on it and a camera. Computers see each other and in the router's webpage, im able to see both of their ip addresses and ping one to another but I cannot see the camera (third device) I switched cables, ports...nothing?

@xxxVxxxlinux Are you sure you don't need to somehow setup the camera first? Most have some kind of initial setup. Or that the camera can work without internet access (e.g. it does not try to access the servers of the manufacturer)? Is the camera turned on?

Initially, the camera is connected through an app called Yoosee. But, I was able to see the camera's RTSP stream through VLC just with it's ip address, no special set up necessary or any servers. It can be seen in any software that reads its IP address

@xxxVxxxlinux and did you setup the camera to connect to your router via the Yoosee app? It seems that the only way to make it connect to WiFi is via that app. So you should try to configure the camera to connect to your new "internet-less" router via the app

I can't because the app requires my phone to be on the same network as the camera when I'm connecting but the app can't work without internet. But, now I tried another camera (different manufacturer) and just plugged its LAN cable into the router and the router webpage recognized it and its IP address. Turns out, the Yoosee cameras are the issue.

I wonder could I fix that it doesn't require cloud or whatever it's looking for?

@xxxVxxxlinux from what I can see, when the Yoosee cameras are newly bought (factory reset), you can configure them to connect to WiFi via SmartLink (requires your phone to be on the same WiFi) or as AP mode (camera starts its own WiFi network..). So it might be that with those cameras you will not be able to achieve what you want. You can try factory resetting the camera and seeing if you can configure it to connect to another WiFi. OR cheat it and put WAN cable to the router and configure internet, then configure the camera to connect to the WiFi (since you will have internet) and unplug WAN

Okay. This thread is getting rather long, so I'll mark your post as answer (I got one camera, am i right?) Thanks for taking time to answer, I'll try to cheat the Yoosee camera to work.


presumably with one computer to act as a server for that.

You don't really need a server, you need networking hardware that supports that. But it'll be useless to have cameras that talk to nothing, so yes, some kind of server will be necessary. I don't know what kind of thing your cameras would talk to (a lot of cheap cameras just… won't talk to anything on a LAN and always want to talk to a server "in the cloud" and become useless when that's not possible), but generally, that works, yes.
There's multiple approaches to that. In an enterprise setting, you'd probably use some Ethernet level authentication ("Radius"/802.1x) to authenticate the devices that may access the internet, but that's probably overkill.
In a pure routing table approach, you could tell your internet router to just not forward packets from the camera's IP addresses to the internet (and vice versa), and that'll be good enough if your cameras behave. If they choose to just use a different IP address or different MAC address, e.g. after a memory failure, well, it's a "if you say you're Timmy, you can't get to the internet. Oh, you say you're Tommy? well, go ahead then!" kind of security measure.
You can, however, physically isolate devices without running new cables, using VLAN technology (which is commonly used since, hm, 1999-ish).
Your "physical LAN" has a switch. If that switch supports VLANs and is "managed", then you can just tell it which network ports are on which VLAN. Simply put all your cameras onto a VLAN that's not the same as your internet router is on, done. You can also set ports that get access to two (or more) VLANs. Connecting your server that way would allow it to get internet access, and to talk to the cameras, without them themselves getting internet access.
Such switches usually aren't very expensive, and chances are, if you have one that does things like PoE for your cameras, it's possibly already built in! Some Wifi internet routers can also do that with their integrated switches.
on your server, in your network manager connection editor (run nm-connection-editor), add a connection, for the Type of that connection use "Virtual" -> "VLAN"; select your ethernet card as "parent device", and as VLAN ID choose the ID that you've assigned to your internet router-facing VLAN. Do the same again with another connection, this time choosing the camera-facing VLAN ID.

Do I need to use any specific software for my server, or some special OS?

well, you need whatever software is able to speak to your cameras. No, you don't need a special OS. I concretely described how this works on any modern Linux distro, so you didn't have to ask that!
